# Compare two columns in excel and extract the differences

Tags: excel, compare

I need to compare two columns and extract only the differences.
For example:

```
Column 1                     Column 2                     Column 3
c:\windows\system32\a.exe    c:\windows\system32\a.exe    null
c:\windows\system32\a.exe    c:\windows\syswow64\a.exe    return system32 or syswow64 / return both of them
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In "Column 3" try using:

```
=IF(A2 = B2, "null", A2 & " " & B2)
```

Where A2 is Column 1, and B2 is Column 2